# Cannot find efficient method for dumping leveldb to flat file(s)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, leveldb

I'm using LevelDB as part of a local process that, when all is done, has ~10-100 million JSON entries.

I need to get these into a portable format, ideally as one or more csv (or even line delimited json) files to import into a separate mongodb system.

I did a quick test in node.js to stream the db contents to a file (using [node-levelup](https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup), and on my machine it took about 18.5 minutes for 10 million pairs. Seems pretty slow.

Looking for suggestions on quicker dump/export from leveldb.

I've considered using mongodb as the store for the local processing, because `mongoexport` is much quicker, but there is a lot more overhead in setup as I'd need several shards to get more speed on my writes.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to retrieve all entries in leveldb is using it's iterator which may node-levelup already did for that.

Since you are still need a tool to parse the exported file, I suggest you just copy leveldb's data dir as the exported file. You can open it and iterate it in python/ruby/..., just any script which have a leveldb wrapper.